# LINQ expression to get the average value from a collection

Tags: c#, linq, average

Is there any LINQ expression that I can use in order to get the average value from a collection, grouped by the `Station` field and return it by date?

Here is my code:

```
public class DatosDto 
{
    public string EstacionSensorEstacionNombre { get; set; }

    public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }

    public float Valor { get; set; }
}
```

I have this code:

```
double average = myCollection.Average(a => a.Valor);
```

Returning this value:

```
 Managua
 Date         Average.
 15-01-2013   15
 16-01-2013   16
 Rio Grande
 15-01-2013   25
 16-01-2013   196
```

Comment: Well, have you worked out how to group by station, to start with? Once you've worked that out, think about how you'd go from that grouping to also group by date. Then you can average by that date...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution. Replace Console.WriteLine with whatever you want to do with it.

```
foreach (var station in myCollection.GroupBy((s) => s.EstacionSensorEstacionNombre))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(station.Key); // station name
            foreach (var date in station.GroupBy((s) => s.Fecha))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(date.Key.ToString() + "   " + date.Average(a => a.Valor)); //date + average value
            }
        }
```

---

You might want to replace

```
(s) => s.Fecha
```

with something that compares only the day/month/year and not the time of the day.

```
(s) => s.Fecha.Year * 1000 + s.Fecha.DayOfYear
```

Kinda hacky but it should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Some fun nested `GroupBy` should do the trick:

```
var grouped = stations
    .GroupBy(s => s.EstacionSensorEstacionNombre) //Get all stations grouped
    .Select(g => new 
    { 
        Station = g.Key,
        DateAverages = g //All of the same named stations
            .GroupBy(sub => sub.Fecha.Date) //Group those by date
            .Select(subg => new 
            { 
                subg.Key, 
                Average = subg.Select(s => s.Valor).Average() 
            })
    });
```

Comment: I get the following error The type '< > f__AnonymousType0 <Averaging >' exists in both ' CaelusReporting.Application.dll ' as in ' CaelusReporting.Web.dll '